# how to return the correct number of objects from array in IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, tableview

I am trying to return the number of objects from myArray and depending on the value, change the headerView in my tableView. The app is functioning in the following way, the user searches for an object, if the object exists the object will appear in the tableView. If the user searches for an object that doesn't exist, nothing will appear in the tableView. Pretty easy..

Eventhough the user searches for an object that doesn't exist it seems like the array stores a value in some-way and the tableView/array is not nil anymore? But nothing is displayed in the tableView. What am I doing wrong? searchResults is the array in my tableView.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.searchResults count];
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)pTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [pTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil)
 {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
Task *task = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *bookLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *chapterLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];

[nameLabel setText:task.name];
[bookLabel setText:task.book.name];
[chapterLabel setText:task.chapter.name];


return cell;
}

- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];

if (self.searchResults == nil){

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lista2.png"]];

    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 5, 18)] autorelease];
    label.text = @"Information";
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerView addSubview:label];
  }

  else if (self.searchResults != nil){

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lista2.png"]];

    UILabel *label2 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 5, 18)] autorelease];
    label2.text = @"Search results";
    label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerView addSubview:label2];
}
return headerView;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it sounds like `self.searchResults` is always non `nil`.

Replace

```
if (self.searchResults == nil){
```

with

```
if ([self.searchResults count] == 0){
```

and replace

```
else if (self.searchResults != nil){
```

with

```
else {
```